# Calling on click on button when timer ends

Tags: android

I'm creating a quiz app in android. I have written OnClickListener  for next button to load next question. now I want to add timer to each question  so that when timer ends it will automatically call OnClickListener of next button. How to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything...?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `performClick()` on an instance of your next button. Something like this:

```
nextButton.performClick()
```

That will execute everything you have inside of `OnClickListener` that is set for that button.

**EDIT:**

If I misunderstood your question and you are searching for Timer implementation, I recommend for you check CountDownTimer that is provided by Android team. You can check documentation with an example for his here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: According to android team i need implement 2 methods in CountDownTimer, onTick and onFinish. What should i write in onFinish method so that when next button click event will be triggered

Comment: Inside of `onFinish` method you just write `nextButton.performClick()` to execute button click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay some code from running for a certain amount of time use a Runnable and a Handler like this

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run(){
    doSomething(); //<-- put your code in here.
}
};

Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method you call when the user clicks the next button say it's named as `nextQuestion()`

then add the listener of your next button

```
 Button nextBtn = findViewById(..);
 nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextQuestion();
            }
        });
```

And the time would be `CountDownTimer` of say 1 min duration (60*1000 msec) and 1 second tick (1000 msec)

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) { // 1 min duration (60*1000 msec) and 1 second tick (1000 msec)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // do something each second
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // timer expired
        nextQuestion();

    }
}.start();
```